# is tex file for memman.pdf (memoir) available?

Tags: memoir

500 page documentation manuals are fine, but I learn best from examples. Lately I've been playing with the memoir class. The pdf documentation is available as memman.pdf. But I would love to see the memman.tex that produced this pdf. Is that available anywhere? It sure would provide a great resource for actually learning memoir. Thanks.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) `memman` uses a lot of custom stuff, not sure if it is a good source for learning memoir.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en) page and click "Download". The zipped file will contain a folder named `doc-src`. The `memman.tex` is in there.

Comment: or go to the `doc-src` folder on the same page.